# ggplot2 scale_x_date in Shiny reactive table

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I have a Shiny app which has both a reactive table, and a `ggplot2` line chart (time series) that uses the reactive table as the dataset.  I am using `scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 week")` in the line chart, and the `min` and `max` values of the dates seen change appropriately with the reactive table.

My problem is that I would like the week intervals to be a Saturday (corresponding with the end of our fiscal week, and all the timestamps in the reactive table) but `ggplot2` defaults to showing Mondays.  How may I change the x-axis to show Saturdays but also scale appropriately in response to the reactive table?

Comment: Not exactly, since the dataset for my ggplot2 object is a reactive table so I don't think I can reference it in the sequence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about like this, borrowing from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16217876/how-to-make-scale-x-date-week-start-with-sunday) but using `lubridate` to set the lowest break at the preceding Saturday?

```
library(lubridate)

scale_x_date(breaks = seq(floor_date(min(data.set$week.start), unit = 'week',
   week_start = getOption('lubridate.week.start', 6)),  max(data.set$week.start),by="week"),
   labels = date_format(format = "%Y-%m-%d"))
```

Comment: I'll try it and see if I can reference the reactive_table() in the sequence

Answer (score 0):

I just needed

```
output$fcstlinechart_weekly <- renderPlotly({
p1 <- ggplot2::ggplot(data= my_reactive_table(),
aes(x=Week_End_Date,y=Forecast)+
  geom_line()+ scale_x_date(
   breaks= unique(data_frame_source_for_reactive_table$Week_End_Date))
p2 <- ggplotly(p1)
p2$elementId <- NULL
p2
})
```

And the plot rendering was "smart enough" to only show date values that exist in the filtered reactive table.